# Shuffle and unshuffle sheet with key

Tags: vba, excel

Catchy title. I'm trying to write an excel macro to shuffle round the cells in a worksheet in a seemingly random way, but so that it can be unshuffled at a later date. However, the key feature here is that the shuffling is dictated by an input key, in my proposed solution this is a number, and the inverse/ unshuffling operation relies on this key too.

My current approach is as follows: *And I summarise below if you don't want to read the details*

- I input a number into a cell on the sheet. I take that number and convert it to something irrational (in my current approach it gets converted to PI() - or at least the correct key is, but another irrational number would do fine).
- Now, every cell in my shuffling array is assigned a unique integer value based on its location. This unique number is combined with the key to give some unique result that is dependant on the key. e.g. `=MID(PI()/10,3, UniqueValue)` - remember PI() was generated by the key, so is dependant on the key's value.
- So for an array `A1:A3` where the unique values are simply `{1,2,3}` then their unique results will be `{1,14,141}`. Those are still in ascending order, so to give a random spread I do `=COS(A1:A3)` or more specifically `=COS(MOD(A1:A3,2*PI()))` to account for numbers outside the range of COS in Excel. That gives me some well mixed up output values.
- Finally I rank output values against eachother to give a new list of unique integer numbers. These new values represent the new positions in the array. The calculation steps for `A1:A3` are from {1, 2, 3} to {0.5403… , 0.13674… , -0.93172} to {1, 2, 3}. Here no randomisation, but for 13 numbers: from from `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}` to `{0.5403… , 0.13674… , -0.93172… , 0.28355… , -0.98753… , 0.91345… , -0.72052… , 0.99538… , -0.6825… , 0.80817… , -0.15975… , 0.38126… , 0.99859}` to `{5, 8, 12, 7, 13, 3, 11, 2, 10, 4, 9, 6, 1}`. That has a nice low correlation between input and output. The only problem here is that PI() is only stored to 16ish dp meaning the `=MID(PI()/10,3, UniqueValue)` can run on at most 13 cells. Consequently I need some way of calculating n digits of PI(), I may have to employ a spigot algorithm.
- Then to unshuffle, simply go to each cell, work out where the cells contents would have been sent, and copy the value in that location back to the original cell

Long story short, a cell has a unique value based on its location. It is assigned a new unique value which is a product of its original value and a separate user input key, and is designed not to correlate with the original value. The new value dictates the new place on the sheet.

### Problems

As stated, my current approach for randomising requires a knowledge of more digits of PI() than Excel holds. Remember though, I am not just using PI() as a constant, it is a variable dictated by my input (likely via an acos() of the input value to get a multiple of PI()) - so I can't just get a text document with a million digits of Pi, I need to be able to calculate many d.p.s of whatever the variable is - I only choose Pi as the *correct key* as a spigot algorithm can be used to generate later digits of PI.

But the randomisation can likely be readily improved. My issue is with the implementation: is generating a new number for each cell the right way to do this? Or is there a much simpler approach for shuffling the sheet that I'm overlooking? And my approach requires alot of temporary copying of values: if I want to shuffle the array but leave it in the same place on the sheet I need protect cells from being copied over as a new cell is moved to their location.

Comment: Just solved the randomising - do away with all the PI and just use `COS(MOD(original number, key))` and rank everything to generate the new location value. Provided key and original value aren't multiples of Pi, Cos should never give duplicate values.

Comment: It's difficult to tell whether your approach is appropriate when you've not explained even briefly what the purpose of the whole exercise is.

Comment: I see the problem, the purpose is to have a sort of document protection that is more physical than password protection/ locking cells. If I have a table of data say, I can shuffle the locations of cells within it so that the data becomes incomprehensible. Plus this approach is easy to implement based on workbook events, and doesn't involve saving a password anywhere (encrypted or not) as the key is mathematical, so any incorrect key should still 'work' - it just won't get the correct shuffle